# CentOS vmtoolsd usage 100%

Tags: centos, virtualbox, cpu

I installed CentOS 7 on VirtualBox but see the CPU usage at 100% by vmtoolsd. I tried multiple ways to bring it down e.g. by doing "lodctr /R" and removing open-vmware-tool but so far no success. I have Windows Host with 16 GB and allocated 8GB to centos vm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`open-vmware-tool` is for running linux under VWMare.  As you are using VirtualBox then you don't need it.

If you remove it, then it cannot use the CPU.  However, if you simply uninstall it with `yum` there is the possibility of it still running as it has already loaded.

It might be worth rebooting the guest (CentOS) after you uninstall it, or alternatively kill `vmtoolsd` with:

```
$ sudo killall vmtoolsd
```

or if you don't use `sudo` on CentOS, as root with:

```
# killall vmtoolsd
```

Comment: What happens if I kill vmtoolsd? I have GNOME installed with VM so does it affect my VM in anyways?

Comment: `vmtoolsd` is only used if your VM is running on VMWare.  Yours isn't as you stated you're running the VM on VirtualBox.  If you don't want to `kill` it, then reboot the VM instead.

Comment: Yep, I killed it and now CPU is flying. Thanks a lot, I was a but reluctant in doing it.